# Photoshop script to get the color of a solid fill layer?

Tags: scripting, photoshop, jsx

I'm trying to write a Photoshop jsx script for extracting color values from a PSD template. The colors are defined as separate fill layers that I'd like to be able to loop through and create a hash of {layer_name: #hex_color} values. I'm not finding any documentation on reading the color value of the fill layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer on [this thread](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=1534&highlight=solidfill).

Comment: Please, can you paste the answer here, because link is unavailable now.

Comment: WE will never know sadly :- (

Comment: @Dariusz Don't be sad :)

Answer (score 2):

This will return the RGB values of the active layer if it's a solidFill layer:

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

if (srcDoc.activeLayer.kind == LayerKind.SOLIDFILL) 
{
  var mySolidFillcol = get_solid_fill_colour();
  alert(mySolidFillcol); //RGB
}

function get_solid_fill_colour()
{
  var r = new ActionReference(); 
  r.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") ); 
  var d = executeActionGet(r);
  var adjList = d.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")); 
  var adjDesc = adjList.getObjectValue(0); 
  var colDesc = adjDesc.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")); 
  var col = new SolidColor(); 
  col.rgb.red   = colDesc.getDouble(charIDToTypeID("Rd  ")); 
  col.rgb.green = colDesc.getDouble(charIDToTypeID("Grn ")); 
  col.rgb.blue  = colDesc.getDouble(charIDToTypeID("Bl  "));
  return [col.rgb.red, col.rgb.green, col.rgb.blue];
}
```